# Write a shell script which will move all files in the current directory containing the word "hello" into a separate folder called "hello-world"

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, files

Write a shell script which will move all files in the current directory containing the word `hello` into a separate folder called `hello-world`.

The current directory contains files `a b c d e` and `f` out of which files `a`, `c` and `f` contain the word `hello`.

How can I search for the word `hello` in files of the current directory and move the files satisfying the condition into another directory `hello-world`?

Comment: That looks like a school assignment. Consider what the `grep` command is able to do.

Comment: `grep "hello" *` gives you not only the filename but also the line containing "hello". Therefore you need to use an option for `grep`: see `man grep` for output control options.

Comment: Then you have to look at how xargs builds up the command: it appends what it gets from stdin to the command. So you have to use the `-t` option in the `mv` command to define the target before the files to be moved. Instead of trying to use a one-liner you could also consider using a little script: first collect the output of the `grep` command in a variable and then use this variable to move the files.

Comment: @muclux are school assignments off topic then?

Comment: @Thufir no, they are not, but in this case we must specifically point the OP to the right direction but not do his/her homework. OP must research and find the answer hxxself.

Answer (score 5):

Let's break this down into smaller tasks. We need to

- create a directory `hello-world`, if it doesn't exist
- reliably identify files that contain the text `hello`
- reliably move the files to the new directory.

Making a directory is done with `mkdir`. It will always refuse to create a directory that exists (thereby refusing to overwrite such directories) but it also has a flag `-p` which, as mentioned in `man mkdir`

```
-p, --parents
       no error if existing, make parent directories as needed
```

doesn't bother to tell you if the directory you are trying to create already exists.

So the first command of our script could be (check you are in the right directory first).

```
mkdir -p hello-world
```

The second step is identifying the files we want. The most obvious command to search for text in files is `grep`. If we wanted only the filenames of the files that contain `hello`, we can use the `-l` flag, which, according to `man grep`

```
-l, --files-with-matches
       Suppress  normal output; instead print the name of each input file
       from which output would normally have been printed.  The scanning
       will stop on the first match.
```

suppresses the normal output. But, although we can get away with it for your example, we really don't want the filenames as output, because the output of a command is just text, and filenames might contain all sorts of characters (from the humble space to the exotic newline) that will cause the shell to see something different from the actual name of the file you want to do something to, and behave in a way you didn't want. For example, having set up a test directory for your script, if I add a file that has a space in its name, see what happens:

```
$ echo hello > with\ space
$ ls
a  b  c  d  e  f  with space
$ for i in $(grep -l hello *); do echo "$i"; done
a
c
f
with
space
```

The file `with space` is treated as two separate files.

To identify files in order to have the shell do something with them, we should avoid parsing filenames. We could test each file, see whether it contains the text, and if it does, move it. To loop over files, as shown above, we can use `for` which has syntax like this:

```
for var in things; do stuff $var; done
```

Inside a `for` loop (and anywhere else too) we can use the `test` command, which sometimes looks like `[` and is also like `[[` to make conditional statements, and if you only wanted to check whether the file was empty or not, or was of a particular type, I would advise you to use the `test` command.

But you want to find some particular text, so we ought to call `grep`, but we only really want to know if looking for `hello` in the file succeeded, so we know that we then have to do something with the file.

To make a conditional statement based on the success of a command, we can use `if`. `if` is often used with `test`/`[`/`[[`, but you don't need those, because `grep` has another useful flag:

```
-q, --quiet, --silent
       Quiet; do not write anything to standard output. Exit immediately
       with zero status if any match is found, even if an error  was detected.
```

Zero in Bash means success. So to do what we want, we could write something like

```
if grep -q hello file; then mv file hello-world; fi
```

(the `fi` is part of the `if` command's syntax. It tells the shell you've finished your `if`)

<sub>I usually write shell scripts in an interactive shell and only scriptify them into a file later if at all, because I'm lazy and I mostly only write very trivial scripts. Anyway, you can write a short script as a one-line command by separating commands with `;`. If something goes wrong, hit the up arrow key to edit the last command...</sub>

We don't want to run that command once for each file. That would defeat the object of writing a script to do the job and save us typing, so to loop over the files we can use `for`. To avoid getting an error from `grep` about the `hello-world` directory, we can add another flag to exclude it.

Here's my test command to do this job and the output I get from it in my test environment:

```
$ mkdir -p hello-world; for file in *; do if grep -q --exclude-dir=hello-world -- hello "$file"; then echo mv -v -- "$file" hello-world; fi; done
mv -v -- a hello-world
mv -v -- c hello-world
mv -v -- f hello-world
mv -v -- with space hello-world
```

This script doesn't move any files, because of `echo` before `mv` which shows what command will be run with each iteration of the loop. Remove `echo` after testing if the commands look right (note that you can't always reliably use `echo` for testing, and you might have to introduce some temporary quoting to do so, but it works fine here).

`*` is all non-hidden files in the current directory. It is safer to use `./*` which means the same thing, but ensures all paths start with `./` (which is the address of the current working directory `.`), preventing filenames starting with `-` being interpreted as options. We have dealt with that possibility by adding `--` to `grep` and to the `mv` command to indicate the end of options. `-v` is `mv`'s verbose flag.

We should quote variables to suppress shell expansions. If I remove the quotes around `"$file"`, my output is

```
mv -v -- a hello-world
mv -v -- c hello-world
mv -v -- f hello-world
grep: with: No such file or directory
grep: space: No such file or directory
```

Here's the script as a script:

```
#!/bin/bash

mkdir -p hello-world
for file in *; do
    if grep -q --exclude-dir=hello-world -- hello "$file"; then
        echo mv -v -- "$file" hello-world
    fi
done
```

Don't forget to remove `echo` when you're ready to move the files for real.

PS, there might well be more efficient ways to do this. My way is just an example.

Comment: That's a totally awesome answer to a mediocre question!  However, if I were you (luckily for you I'm not), I wouldn't have included the script at the end though so the pupil would still have had to figure out some things for herself, but upvoted anyway!  **:-) :-) :-)**

Comment: Agree! Awesome answer, but you spoiled the kid!

Answer (score 0):

This would be a solution following your idea with grep and xargs:

```
#!/bin/bash
mkdir hello-world
grep -l hello * | xargs mv -t hello-world
```

Comment: That should work for OP, but will fail if filenames have spaces...

Comment: The `-Z` and `-0` options may help with that.

Answer (score -1):

From a bash script named `test.sh`

```
#!/bin/sh
IFS=$'\n'
for i in $( grep -l hello --exclude=*.sh --exclude-dir=hello-world * ); do mv $i hello-world/; done;
```

From command line:

```
IFS=$'\n' && for i in $( grep -l hello --exclude-dir=hello-world * ); do mv $i hello-world/; done;
```

Hopes it helps you...

Please consider to create first directory hello-world.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, I've edited my answer...

Comment: well, that's a little better but it will still break if filenames have spaces (quoting won't fix it)

Comment: Thanks a lot @zanna, what about now?

Comment: I already undid my downvote, but see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/321697/why-is-looping-over-finds-output-bad-practice/321757#321757 for the general problems with this kind of approach

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, it is more important knowledge than votes.

Comment: Thanks a lot for improving your answer :) PS There's nothing wrong with posting an answer that works only in some situations, as long as you mention when it will not work!